# C++ File input works once, but not twice for the same file

Tags: c++, io

So I am running a program that has the users input a command. I have a text file with a list of acceptable command words. I open the file first to make sure that what the user input is indeed a valid command, but after that step I close the file. After that, I use some if/else statements to run a function corresponding to the command. One command is to list all of the valid commands, which requires me to open the file again and simply output the contents. At this step, however, the program simply outputs nothing. Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

void mainMenu();
void comJunc(string comString);
void comList();
bool isCommand(string comString);

int main()
{
    mainMenu();

    return 0;
}
void mainMenu()//This function inputs a command
{
    string comString;
    bool isCom = false;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "||Welcome to the main menu||\n\nPlease enter a command. For a list of commands type \"comlist\"\n";

    do
    {
        cout << ">";
        cin >> comString;//Input command "comlist"
        isCom = isCommand(comString);//Checks if command is valid
        if(isCom == false)
            cout << endl << "**Error** Command \"" << comString << "\" was not found. Type \"comlist\" for help\n";
    }while(isCom == false);

    comJunc(comString);

    return;
}
bool isCommand(string comString)
{
    bool sFlag = false;
    string inString;

    ifstream comFile;
    if(comFile.is_open() == false)
    {
        comFile.open("commands.txt");
    }

    while(getline(comFile, inString))
    {
        if(comString == inString)
            sFlag = true;
    }

    comFile.close();
    return sFlag;
}
void comJunc(string comString)//Executes function based on command
{
    //comlist, continue, start, customize, exit
    if(comString == "comlist")
    {
      comList();//Calles comList function
  }
    else if(comString == "exit")
    {
        //does nothing (exits)
    }
    else
        cout << "Error in comJunc";

    return;
}
void comList()
{
    string inString;
    ifstream comFile;

    if(comFile.is_open() == false)
    {
        comFile.open("command.txt");
    }

    while(getline(comFile, inString))//This loop is not executed
    {
        cout << "Random text";//Text is not displayed
        cout << endl << inString;
    }
    cout << endl;
    comFile.close();

    return;
}
```

The console looks like this:

---

||Welcome to the main menu||

Please enter a command. For a list of commands type "comlist"
>

---

At which point I type "comlist"
The desired result is for the command.txt file to output its contents. It should look like this:

---

comlist 
command2 
command3 
command4 
command5

---

Instead, the screen is left blank and the program exits as usual.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That `is_open` call is always going to be `false`, you should have it *after* you open the file, and if the file is not opened then you should handle it. Also, you don't need an explicit `return` statement in a function returning `void`, the function will return anyway once it ends.

Comment: As for your problem, you should create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us how the functions are called, what happens between the two calls to `isCommand` and `comList`?

Comment: And you don't change the process working directory in between the calls?

Comment: Nothing changes in between calls. The only thing that happens is the program determines which function to execute based on the input command. That's all I have, the program utilizes isCommand to determine if the input word is a command, and then if the command is "comlist", then it executes the comList function (this is done with if/else statements), but the comList function doesn't behave properly.

Comment: There is nothing in the code shown that could explain such a behavior, that means the problem is in the code you do not show us. I reiterate, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and *edit your question* to show us. Also, in the question, show us input and actual/expected output that causes this behavior for the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My sincerest apologies, thank you for trying to be patient with me. I'm a bit new here and haven't quite figured out all of the formatting. As well, I left out much of the code in attempt to create a MCVE because much of the code didn't seem important. I'm baffled as to why the program is behaving this way.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems with the posted code, the only thing I can think about is if you mistyped the file-name in one of the functions, and on POSIX systems (like Linux or OSX) such misspellings include upper- and lower-case letter mismatch. Or if you managed to, by mistake, write some non-printable character in the file-name string in one function.

Comment: Oh my God. I found it. I did mistype the file name. I'm so sorry to waste your time. In the first function I open "commands.txt", but for the second one I open "command.txt". I just forgot the s. Thanks for all your help though.